# jQuery how to order the jquery to dynamically add div then run second call

Tags: jquery, slider, bxslider

I need to dynamically add a div around items then run a second bit to make the item rotate.

So far I can add the div but the second part doesn't load like it needs to.

```
<div id="ContentFeed">
<div class="newsItem">Text</div>
<div class="newsItem">Text</div>
<div class="newsItem">Text</div>
<div class="newsItem">Text</div>
<div class="newsItem">Text</div>
</div>

<script>$('#ContentFeed .newsItem').wrapAll('<div id="slider" />');</script>


    <div id="ContentFeed">
     <div id="slider">
        <div class="newsItem">Text</div>
        <div class="newsItem">Text</div>
        <div class="newsItem">Text</div>
        <div class="newsItem">Text</div>
        <div class="newsItem">Text</div>
    </div>
   </div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#slider').bxSlider({
        auto: false,
        displaySlideQty: 6,
        moveSlideQty: 6,
        pagerType: short,
        pager: true
  });
});
</script>
```

Any idea how to get the second part to see the dynamically added div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be trying to add the dynamic div too early, try wrapping the first bit of jQuery code in the same `document.ready` event handler:

```
$(function(){
    $('#ContentFeed .newsItem').wrapAll('<div id="slider" />');
    $('#slider').bxSlider({
        auto            : false,
        displaySlideQty : 6,
        moveSlideQty    : 6,
        pagerType       : short,
        pager           : true
    });
});
```

You can verify if this is the issue by inspecting the DOM to see if the `#slider` element is actually being added to the DOM.

Comment: @Ashlee There may be another error that is blocking execution, because in an isolated case this works. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JZLEy/. Can you post a link to the error?

Comment: After looking at this again I realized I had called the wrong item. It is now working! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using the `.on` method

something like `$(document).on("ready", function(){ your slider code...`
and probably wrap the other cod in that too.

read about it here

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: `.on()` is the new way to bind events in jQuery 1.7, but `$(document).on("ready", function(){/*code here*/});` is the same thing as: `$(function () {/*code here*/});`

Comment: Can you be more specific I don't understand how this could be used after reading the link you gave.

Comment: hmm.  I'm still somewhat used to using the live function but it was just deprecated.  Ashlee JAspers right then.  It should just be the order of your code.  is your console throwin errors?